# Adding custom keys to Sensu clients

Tags: sensu

I am trying to add custom keys/values in a sensu client via the sensu API:

```
curl -X POST localhost:4567/clients -d '{"name":"test-sensu","address":"test-address","subscriptions":[], "custom":"value"}'
```

The custom label is added (along with a "keepalives" : false) but a few seconds later, when the next keepalive for this client is received, the label gets discarded.

Does this mean that dynamic context data is only allowed for JIT clients?

Comment: Does it persist if you include "custom" since the beginning, since registration time (like "mysql" on https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/clients#custom-definition-attributes) ?

Comment: Yes, it does. But I need to add keys dynamically

Comment: I now is really not an answer, but you could try and take a look at the code: https://github.com/sensu/sensu/blob/master/lib/sensu/api/process.rb sometimes I have had the necessity to check it when something is now clearly documented